# ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.dll' (errno: 126) The specified module could not be found.)

Tags: java, mysql, dll

i'm trying to execute: i'm following this [GitHub](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_str/blob/master/README.win_x86.txt#L42)

```
mysql> CREATE FUNCTION sys_exec RETURNS INT SONAME 'lib_mysqludf_sys.dll';
```

on MYSQL CLI. But getting this error.

> ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'lib_mysqludf_sys.dll'
>   (errno: 126)  The specified module could not be found.)

[image: MYSQL CLI]
but **lib_mysqludf_sys.dll** is present at default installation location

> C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\lib\plugin

i have to call **restful web service url** from **UDF** on trigger in MYSQL.
i'm using windows 8 64bit, MYSQL 5.6

i already googled it and all available similar questions on **stackoverflow** 
 i.e [Possible similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28665934/invoking-an-http-get-request-through-mysql-by-executing-native-operating-system) but no luck.

any suggestions? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be exporting your endpoint.

May be you can find something here on this link for UDF development that you might be missing something at some step
https://github.com/esabilbulbul/mysql-udf-windows